# Is this strong or weak?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

Suppose this situation:

```
__weak UIImage *image = [self calculateImage];

// a few lines later...

image = [self calculateImageUsingAnotherProcess];
```

Supposing `calculateImage` and `calculateImageUsingAnotherProcess` returning strong references.

OK, in the first case `image` is `weak` but what about the second? Will `image` maintain the `weak` aspect?

Comment: As per my knowledge, it's a way of strong to weak, image (as a weak) will be in memory until a strong reference will be pointing to it.

Comment: what? the way you explained that sounded like klingon and my brain melted. 

Comment: how calculateImage and calculateImageUsingAnotherProcess returning strong references. ?  image object is weak means it is weak , doesn't matter what it is pointing

Comment: ok, I meant not weak by definition.

Comment: It never makes any sense to declare a weak local variable unless it's being captured by a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second one will stay weak as well. It cannot be changed after the declaration.

Comment: thanks! I was just checking to see if I was understanding it correctly...

Comment: No problem :) It is normal to ask this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a strong reference in that sense. It's the container where the reference is put that dictates whether it is strong, weak or otherwise. If you've declared a `weak` container then any reference you assign to it will be held weakly.

By convention the thing returned by `calculateImageUsingAnotherProcess` will be unowned other than by the autorelease pool.

So, although true, it's not so much that the strength of a reference "cannot be changed after the declaration", it's that there is no mechanism that allows you to attempt to do so and, correspondingly, no such attempt in your code.